# MySQL Join Query

Tags: mysql, join, aggregate-functions

I need to query the database by joining two tables. Here is what I have:

Table Town:

- id
- name
- region

Table Supplier:

- id
- name
- town_id

I currently have the following query which outputs all the Towns that belong to a given region:

```
SELECT id, name FROM Town WHERE region = 'North West';
```

Now I need to extend this query and create two further queries as follows:

- Output the number of Suppliers for each Town
- Output only the Towns that have 1 or more Supplier

I am using PHP for my scripts if that helps. I know I may be able to to get this data using PHP but in terms of performance it will probably be better if it is done in MySQL.

**EDIT (27/07/10):**

I now needs to extend this one last time - there is another table called Supplier_vehicles:

- id
- supplier_id
- vehicle_id

A Supplier can have many Supplier_vehicles. The count (NumSupplier in this case) needs to now contain the total number of suppliers in a given town that have any of the given vehicle_id (IN condition):

```
SELECT * FROM Supplier s, Supplier_vehicles v WHERE s.id = v.supplier_id AND v.vehicle_id IN (1, 4, 6)
```

Need to integrate the above query into the existing JOIN query.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Count the number of suppliers.

```
SELECT t.id, t.name, count(s.id) as NumSupplier
FROM Town t
LEFT OUTER JOIN Suppliers s ON s.town_id = t.id
GROUP BY t.id, t.name
```

Only towns that have at least one supplier

```
SELECT DISTINCT t.id, t.name
FROM Town t
INNER JOIN Suppliers s ON s.town_id = t.id
```

And you are 100% correct, the best place for this is an SQL query.

Comment: Hi Chris, on that first query I'm only getting back one row, and that's the very first record in my Town table...

Comment: On that second solution (Only towns that have at least one supplier) if I also wanted to output the number of suppliers I can add in the COUNT and GROUP BY functions as in the first solution. I found however that I can take out DISTINCT and it will still give me the same results. So does it actually make any difference if we have DISTINCT or not?

Comment: How can we extend the first query further to give a count of only the suppliers (within each town) that have field "Suppliers.enabled=1"? I tried adding this as a WHERE clause but it does not return all the rows in the table.

Comment: `GROUP BY` makes it `DISTINCT` because it will only display one row for each id/name with `GROUP BY`. `DISTINCT` only returns one of each row that is returned by the query. To make suppliers.enabled work, put it in the join so it becomes `LEFT OUTER JOIN Suppliers s ON s.town_id = t.id AND s.enabled = 1`

Comment: Finally is it possible to retrieve the total count of the NumSupplier field?

Comment: If every supplier has a town then it is `SELECT COUNT(id) FROM Suppliers`

Comment: If every supplier has a town then they are equivalent, or just remove the first two columns in the select and the group by.

Comment: Hi Chris, can you take a look at my recent edit please? Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by intergrate into the first query. You should ask another question, giving an example of what you expect the output to be.

Comment: Cheers, have posted a new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3343138/mysql-join-query-possible-two-inner-joins

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t.id, t.name, count(s.id) as NumSupplier
FROM Town t
LEFT JOIN Suppliers s
[WHERE NumSupplier > 1]
GROUP BY t.id
```