# MySQL Join Query (possible two inner joins)

Tags: mysql, join, aggregate-functions

I currently have the following:

Table Town:

- id
- name
- region

Table Supplier:

- id
- name
- town_id

The below query returns the number of suppliers for each town:

```
SELECT t.id, t.name, count(s.id) as NumSupplier
FROM Town t 
INNER JOIN Suppliers s ON s.town_id = t.id 
GROUP BY t.id, t.name
```

I now wish to introduce another table in to the query, Supplier_vehicles. A supplier can have many vehicles:

Table Supplier_vehicles:

- id
- supplier_id
- vehicle_id

Now, the NumSupplier field needs to return the number of suppliers for each town that have any of the given vehicle_id (IN condition):

The following query will simply bring back the suppliers that have any of the given vehicle_id:

```
SELECT * FROM Supplier s, Supplier_vehicles v WHERE s.id = v.supplier_id AND v.vehicle_id IN (1, 4, 6)
```

I need to integrate this in to the first query so that it returns the number of suppliers that have any of the given vehicle_id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT t.id, t.name, count(s.id) as NumSupplier
FROM Town t 
INNER JOIN Suppliers s ON s.town_id = t.id 
WHERE s.id IN (SELECT sv.supplier_id
               FROM supplier_vehicles sv 
               WHERE sv.vehicle_id IN (1,4,6))
GROUP BY t.id, t.name
```

Or you could do an `INNER JOIN` (as your supplier join is INNER, but this will remove towns with no suppliers with those vehicles) and change the `COUNT(s.id)` TO `COUNT(DISTINCT s.id)`

Comment: Cheers, this seems to be working fine. Will continue testing.

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly, you can put your second query inside the LEFT OUTER JOIN condition.

So for example, you can do something like

...
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT * FROM Suppler s, Supplier_vehicles ......) s ON s.town_id=t.id

In that way you are "integrating" or combining the two queries into one. Let me know if this works.

Comment: Apologies, it is actually an INNER JOIN. And it has not worked I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t.name, count(s.id) as NumSupplier
FROM Town t
LEFT OUTER JOIN Suppliers s ON t.id = s.town_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN Supplier_vehicles v ON s.id = v.supplier_id
WHERE v.vehicle_id IN (1,4,6)
GROUP BY t.name
```

Comment: If a supplier has more than one vehicle then your query would count the same supplier twice.

Comment: Also you are reducing the `supplier_vehicles` join to an `INNER JOIN` by filtering on `vehicle_id` in the `WHERE` clause